# Test calls async method which returns 'Value cannot be null'

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await

I have an async method which I'm trying to unit test, specifically I want to test that the async method returns a `NoContent` response given that no customer entities were found. Here is the method in question:

```c#
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("customers/{customerNumber}")]
    public virtual async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get([FromUri] CustomerNumber customerNumber)
    {
        var customerEntitiesList = _tableStorageService.GetCustomerEntities(customerNumber);
        var customersList = customerEntitiesList.Select(customerEntity => customerEntity.PartitionKey).ToList();
        if (customersList.Any()) {
            return await Task.FromResult(Ok(customersList));
        }
        return await Task.FromResult(ResponseMessage(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, "No content found.")));
    }
```

To clarify, `CustomerNumber` is a string representation class and looks like this:

```c#
[DebuggerDisplay("{ToString()}")]
public class CustomerNumber
{
    public CustomerNumber(string customerNumber);

    public static bool TryParse(string customerNumber, out CustomerNumber parsedCustomerNumber);
    public override string ToString();

    public static implicit operator string(CustomerNumber customerNumber);
    public static implicit operator CustomerNumber(string customerNumber);
}
```

And here is the unit test:

```c#
    [Test]
    public async Task Should_Return_No_Content_If_Customer_Entities_Are_Not_Found()
    {
        const string customerNumber = "WP0000000000";
        var customerEntitiesStub = new List<CustomerEntity>();
        A.CallTo(() => _tableStorageServiceDummy.GetCustomerEntities(customerNumber)).Returns(customerEntitiesStub);

        var result = await _companyController.Get(customerNumber);

        ((ResponseMessageResult)result).Response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

When I run this test, it just fails before even completing with the error `System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.`. Why is this happening and how can I fix it so that I can assert the result? Thanks!

Comment: The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete and would require too many questions to clarify what is being asked. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem, allowing us to better understand what is being asked.

Comment: There is actually no reason to have the action return a task. nothing is actually being done async.

Comment: You also setup the mock to expect a `string` but the actual method has a `CustomerNumber` parameter. start investigating there. Because the setup does not match, the `customerEntitiesList` would be null when the `GetCustomerEntities` is invoked.

Comment: @Nkosi Not only that, but it also unnecessarily wraps, then unwraps, then re-wraps, the result into a `Task`.  If there *is* a reason for the method to return a `Task` (none of which I could imagine being applicable to an HTTP endpoint) it's still doing superfluous work.

Answer (score 0):

The mock is setup to expect a `string` but the actual method has a `CustomerNumber` parameter. Start investigating there.

Because the setup does not match, the `customerEntitiesList` would be `null` when the `GetCustomerEntities` is invoked.

Assuming `CustomerNumber` can be implicitly converted from a string then the test should be configured with an actual `CustomerNumber` instance.

```
[Test]
public async Task Should_Return_No_Content_If_Customer_Entities_Are_Not_Found() {
    const CustomerNumber customerNumber = "WP0000000000";
    var customerEntitiesStub = new List<CustomerEntity>();
    A.CallTo(() => _tableStorageServiceDummy.GetCustomerEntities(customerNumber)).Returns(customerEntitiesStub);

    var result = await _companyController.Get(customerNumber);

    ((ResponseMessageResult)result).Response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

On a separate not the design of that action wraps the result in tasks. There is currently no reason for that action to be async.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("customers/{customerNumber}")]
public virtual IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri] CustomerNumber customerNumber)
{
    var customerEntitiesList = _tableStorageService.GetCustomerEntities(customerNumber);
    var customersList = customerEntitiesList.Select(customerEntity => customerEntity.PartitionKey).ToList();
    if (customersList.Any()) {
        return Ok(customersList);
    }
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, "No content found.");
}
```

and update the test accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Sorry for not being clear, as a matter of fact CustomerNumber is a string representation class. So the setup works fine and customerEntitiesList is an empty list, I'll update the question with this info.

Comment: @SirarSalih when debugging, where exactly do you get the exception in the method under test.

Comment: @SirarSalih in that case that only leaves the `Request` Did you create a request for the test and assign it to the controller?